# how we can assign single value of array to any variable in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?php
$abc=array();
$abc = (abc, cde,fre);
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
var gdf = "<?php echo $lat['i'];?>";
alert("value ="+gdf);
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you accept some of your other answers, we may be more willing to help.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what the problem is.

Comment: You code literally makes no sense. Where does $lat come from? The second $abc line is not the correct way to initialize your array with array pieces, either.

Comment: actually i want to assign value of array to signal variable in javascript and show that value as alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your comment, I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
<?php

$abc = array('abc', 'cde', 'fre');

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var gdf = '<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < count($abc); $i++) {
    echo "{$abc[$i]}";
    if ($i != (count($abc)-1)) echo ", ";
}

?>';
</script>
```

Will output:

http://codepad.org/KjEH5CmN

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gdf = 'abc, cde, fre';
</script>
```

**NOTE**

Using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) if you want a single variable would also work well:

http://codepad.org/UwukCY4m

```
<?php

$abc = array('abc', 'cde', 'fre');

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var gdf = '<?php echo implode(', ',$abc); ?>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not looking to assign a single value of the array; you're looking for the whole array. Your JavaScript loop is trying to iterate over the entire `$abc` array from PHP.

Something like this would work:

```
var abc = <?php echo json_encode($abc); ?>;
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    var gdf = abc[i];
    alert("value = " + gdf);
}
```

Comment: `<?=` is deprecated, please don't use it.

Comment: @halfdan - Do you have an official PHP statement to that effect? The last I heard, it was still not determined that 6 would officially deprecate them, but that was a while back.

Comment: <?php
$abc=array('abc', 'cde', 'fre');
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var abc = ['<?php echo implode("', '", $abc) ?>'];

    for ( var i = 0; i < abc.length; i++ ) {
        alert('value=' + abc[i]);
    }
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to build a PHP array you should be using this notation:

```
<?php

$abc = array('abc', 'cde', 'fre');

?>
```

Next, it's not possible use JavaScript to directly loop through your variable that is stored in PHP. You can do something like this instead, performing the loop in PHP:

```
<?php
$abc=array('abc', 'cde', 'fre');
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <?php foreach ( $abc as $el ): ?>
    alert('value=<?php echo $el ?>');
    <?php endforeach ?>
</script>
```

Or, if you'd really like the loop to happen in JavaScript and not PHP, you can "export" the PHP array to JavaScript by converting the array to a JSON string and outputting it.

```
<?php
$abc=array('abc', 'cde', 'fre');
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var abc = <?php echo json_encode($abc) ?>;

    for ( var i = 0; i < abc.length; i++ ) {
        alert('value=' + abc[i]);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I fairly sure he's only having an alert there to test his code. What he really wants is use the values in his JavaScript..

Comment: Yes, the `alert` is just to demonstrate the technique. It can be replaced with any code he likes.

Comment: `json_encode` is better than building the array (more or less) manually.

Comment: @Felix Thanks, you're right. I updated my post to use `json_encode`.

Comment: @HansEngel this kind of spaghetti combination of php and js makes me sad.